# Gitlab: Maintainer permissions when shared group with group not working as expected

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

I am running a gitlab-ce instance where we solve access level on group level by sharing groups with user groups. An example:

There is a group `products` with a couple of projects in there. No user is directly added as member to that group. There is another group called `developers`. Product developers are  added to `developers` with *maintainer* access.

The group `products` is shared with `developers` with a maximum role of *maintainer*.

With that I would assume, that I can transfer a project that I am owner of to group `products`. However, the list of groups I can transfer my project to only contains groups where I am a direct member with the *maintainer* role.

TLDR:

- Group `products` is shared with group `developers` with max role *maintainer*
- User **Bob** is member of `developers` with the *maintainer* role
- **Bob** is owner of project `bobs_project`
- **Bob** cannot transfer `bobs_project` to `products` (but he *could* transfer it to `developers`)

From my understanding of the relevant [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/#share-a-group-with-another-group) **Bob** should have the same rights in `products` as someone directly added as *maintainer* to `products`. However, that seems not to be the case.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

A [few points from the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/#transfer-a-group) you reference might be relevant in your setup:

> When transferring groups, note:
>
> - You can only transfer groups to groups you manage.
> - Only explicit group membership is transferred, not inherited membership. If the group’s owners have only inherited membership, this leaves the group without an owner. In this case, the user transferring the group becomes the group’s owner.

Here, Bob has *inherited* rights in `products`, not direct rights. That might explain why the group is not listed.